# Dot (.) in Schema name makes pg_dump unusable

Tags: postgresql, schema, pg-dump

I have a schema named `2sample.sc`. When I want to pg_dump some of its table, the following error appears:

```
pg_dump: No matching tables were found
```

My pg_dump command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -t 2sample.sc."error_log" --inserts games > dump.sql
```

My pg_dump works fine on other schemas like 2sample.

**What I did:**

- I tried to escape dot(.) with no success though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `"schema.name.with.dots.in.it"."table.name.with.dots.in.it"` to specify the `schema.table`:

```
        -- test schema with a dot in its name
DROP SCHEMA "tmp.tmp" CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA "tmp.tmp" ;
SET search_path="tmp.tmp";

CREATE TABLE nononono
        ( dont SERIAL NOT NULL
        );

insert into nononono
SELECT generate_series(1,10)
        ;
```

---

```
$pg_dump -t \"tmp.tmp\".\"nononono\" --schema-only -U postgres the_database
```

Output (snipped):

```
SET search_path = "tmp.tmp", pg_catalog;
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: nononono; Type: TABLE; Schema: tmp.tmp; Owner: postgres; Tablespace:
--

CREATE TABLE nononono (
    dont integer NOT NULL
);
```

BTW: **why** would you want to add a dot to a schema (or table) name? It is asking for trouble. The same for MixedCaseNames. Underscores work just fine.

Comment: it is all in the manual `--schema "the_name"` (or `-n "the_name"` ) should work. The shell may eat the `"` so you'll have to escape the quotes by prepending backslashes.

Comment: I'm working with an existing project. If I were them, I'd definitely used _ or something else.

Comment: IMHO you(they) should refactor it ASAP. It is only a day of work or so. The effort will pay back within a year or so. It is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: We'll do ASAP. Thanks for your recommendation.